# Symfony 4, remove blank fields in forms

Tags: forms, symfony4

```
 ->add('bill', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => \App\Entity\Bill::class,
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => "js-example-basic-single",
                ],
                'label' => false,
                'required' => true,
                'choice_label' => function ($bill) {
                    $sumPrice = 0;
                    $sumPayment = 0;
                    foreach ($bill->getCost() as $item) {
                        $sumPrice = $sumPrice + $item->getPrice();
                        foreach ($bill->getPayment() as $pay) {
                            $sumPayment = $sumPayment + $pay->getMoney();
                        }
                        $sum = $sumPayment - $sumPrice;
                        if ($sum != 0) {
                            return
                                $bill->getPlayers()->getName() . " " .
                                $sum;
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]);
```

And everything work fine, and i get only players that sum != 0, and for the rest players, I dont get players name (which is ok), but i get blank space, and I dont know how to remove it

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Perhaps you can reformulate your post into a clear question and describe better what you are trying to do. There is an FAQ here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is happening because you have your callback function in the `choice_label` option, so you are only modifying the labels. What you want to modify are the choices, so use the `choices` option instead and put the logic where it belongs, like in a controller or repository. To modify the label, define a `__toString()` function in your entity.